# Determining where a Rust program starts and ends

Tags: rust

Can you specify where a Rust program starts executing like you can in C? Or does it always start at `main`? In addition, can you specify where it ends or does it always end at the end of the main scope?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but how can you do that in C?

Comment: You can use `std::process::exit` (like C's `exit`) to quit early.

Answer (score 2):

Review the [documentation for avoiding the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/no-stdlib.html). You are looking for the attribute `start`:

```
// Entry point for this program
#[start]
fn start(_argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    0
}
```

And yes, normal execution flow must return back through here. I'm not sure how it plays with panicking.

Comment: This does allow matching C exactly (i.e. a function marked `#[start]` is 100% equivalent to C's `main`), but isn't where a Rust program typically starts: most programs will go through [`std::rt::lang_start`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cc30948720d152f73e48f8f322ac3f9da18e72cd/src/libstd/rt.rs#L41), which is executed directly by C's `main`, being passed a function pointer to the Rust `main` and the argv/argc.

Comment: @huon would the next part of the docs ("overriding the `main` shim") correspond to what you mean? I can add that to the example as well.

Comment: I think so, yeah, although you can't actually create a new version of `lang_start` if `std` is imported (lang items can be defined at most once in a dependency graph).